# Spring-roo warnings. And removal !

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, aspectj, spring-roo

I have been testing Roo in the last few days..

I am getting the following 3 warnings (on both samples and my own projects) and I don't know why. I haven't used AspectJ before either so I have no idea what they mean..
The warnings appear with "mvn package" command, but not with "roo perform package".

Anything I should need to know or do for this ?

```
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

Also, on a second matter, while reading the reference document I came across the removal of Roo.
There was a part saying I needed to "refactor -> push in" on the project. (I think this means to delete all .aj and move the relevant code blocks to the respective .java files.)
So.. I can press "Push In" in Eclipse but it says "No crosscutting model available".
Same question here.. anything I should need to know ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the second part of the question just refer to [the following thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=98075). You need full rebuild of your project first with Eclipse's `Project -> Clean...`.

What about the first part I suppose you should just ignore them. As far as I understand there are some AspectJ advises in Spring framework which don't applied because there are no corresponding annotations declared in your project. As far as you don't need these annotation there is no problem with that.